# Orlicz space is complete under the Luxemburg norm

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove that Orlicz space is complete. Here is my attempt

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measurable space and suppose $\phi(x)$ is a young function. Define $$L^{\phi}=\{f\hspace{0.2cm} \text{measurable:}\int_{X}\phi(|f(x)|/M)d\mu<\infty, \text{for some}\hspace{0.2cm} M>0\}$$ 
And $||f||_{\phi}=\inf_{M>0}\int_{X}\phi(|f(x)|/M)d\mu\le1$.
I want to prove that $L_{\phi}$ is complete in  this norm.

I thought of the following:

**step one**
let $\{ f_n \}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^{\phi}$, then $\forall \epsilon > 0$
$\exists$ a positive integer $N$ s.t $\forall$ $n>m>N$ we have $\|f_n-f_m\| < \epsilon$.

Now, for all $n>m>N$ the following is true $\int_{X}\phi(\frac{|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|}{\|f_n-f_m\|})d\mu\le1$. 
Can I deduce from here that the quantity $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n>m>N$? I thought I could since everything is fixed ($\phi$, $X$, the bound 1) but the $\|f_n-f_m\|<\epsilon$ and here that epsilon is arbitrary. If this deduction is correct. I then want to proceed as follows:

**step two**
construct a pointwise limit $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ of $f_n$ on $X$ s.t
$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$

**step three**
prove that $f$ is indeed in $L^{\phi}$ and that $\|f_n-f\|\to 0$

I appreciate any help or hints.

Comment: Answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4544715/291842)